# Is there a way to find if the iOS app is in background from Pusher Gem?

Tags: ios, pusher, pusherswift

Server: Pusher gem(rails) Client: Pusher Swift

How do I detect if the client is gone offline(app in background) or come back online(app in foreground) using Pusher gem?

What I want to achieve is sending APN to the client, when the client enters background without querying client online flag(s).

Is it possible to achieve this? Is there way to check the status of Event trigger if the message was received by client or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can achieve what you're trying to do.

If you're using a single channel per client you can use the `channel_existence` webhooks as described [here](https://pusher.com/docs/webhooks#channel-existence). As each channel is limited to a single user, you will receive a `channel_vacated` webhook whenever your client goes offline and a `channel_occupied` webhook whenever your client comes online.

If you're not using a single channel per client, you could use[presence channels](https://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_presence_channels) and webhooks. You can configure a `member_added`/`member_removed` webhook every time a user joins/leaves a channel. There is an additional message overhead associated with this, as each user in the channel will also receive a `member_added`/`member_removed` webhook over the websocket connection.

Comment: Hey there, 

I don't think the channel gets disconnected when the client's app goes in the background. And I noticed from the Pusher debug console that, if the client locks his device(iPhone) only then channel gets disconnected, which will help me to send APN, but the problem still remains when the app is in background.

Comment: Sorry, in your question you said "offline", so I assumed you meant you wanted to know when the websocket is disconnected.